# Não é possível ler os dados da conexão de transporte: Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexão existente pelo host remoto

Tags: c#, importação, host, webrequest

Estou tentando fazer uma leitura de arquivo no estilo "csv". Após a leitura tenho que adicioná-lo ao banco, porém recebo o seguinte erro = "***Não é possível ler os dados da conexão de transporte: Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexão existente pelo host remoto.***". Estou fazendo a leitura do arquivo diretamente da url. Obs: quando faço um While de poucas repetições ele funciona e adiciona no banco normalmente.

```
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                int count = 0;

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string linha = reader.ReadLine();
                    string[] valores = linha.Split('|');
                    if (count != 0)
                    {   
                        try{
                            DtoProduto produto = new DtoProduto();
                            char[] mychar = { 'B', 'R', 'L', '"' };
                            char[] contra = { '\\', '"', '>' };
                            valores[0] = valores[0].Trim(contra);
                            valores[1] = valores[1].Trim(contra);
                            valores[2] = valores[2].Trim(contra);
                            valores[3] = valores[3].Trim(contra);
                            valores[7] = valores[7].Trim(contra);
                            valores[9] = valores[9].Trim(contra);
                            valores[13] = valores[13].Trim(contra);
                            valores[4] = valores[4].Trim(mychar);
                            valores[4] = valores[4].Substring(0, valores[4].IndexOf('.') + 1);

                            decimal preco = decimal.Parse(valores[4]);
                            string categoria = valores[13].Substring(0, valores[13].IndexOf(">") - 1);
                            produto.Id = int.Parse(valores[1]);
                            produto.IdBrand = 4;
                            produto.IdProdutoIntegracao2 = valores[0];
                            produto.Nome = valores[2];
                            produto.Descricao = valores[3];
                            produto.UrlFoto = valores[7];
                            produto.UrlProduto = valores[9];
                            produto.Preco = preco;
                            produto.Situacao = EnSituacaoProduto.Ativo;
                            produto.Categorias = ObterCategorias(categoria);

                            List<int> genero = new List<int>();

                            if (valores[23].ToLower() != "adult")
                            {
                                genero.Add(3);
                            }
                            if (valores[22].ToLower() == "unisex")
                            {
                                genero.Add(1);
                                genero.Add(2);
                            }else if (valores[22].ToLower() == "mulher") {
                                genero.Add(2);
                            } else {
                                genero.Add(2);
                            }
                            produto.Generos = genero.ToArray();

                            Listproduto.Add(produto);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            string nomeArquivo = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"uploads\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".txt";
                            StreamWriter log = new StreamWriter(nomeArquivo);
                            log.WriteLine("Erro ao salvar produto " + linha);
                            log.Close();
                        }
                    }

                    count++;
                }
```

Comment: muto provavel algum bloqueio ao acessar ao dp por disparar varias acessoas a ele,  está usando qual SGDB e qual  tipo  de Conexão ao banco?
tente criar apenas  uma conexão de entrada inserir todo o dado e depois fecha-la deve resolver

Comment: estou usando Sql server executando a persistência de dados pelo linq via conexão pela classe contextDB.

Comment: você está dando db.Dispose(); no  sue banco ?? pois cada vez que o loop entra ele deve está abrindo uma nova conexão e não fecando  de Dispose() na sua conexão linq

Comment: lembrando que o  db ai é a sua instacia do  Contexto que está utilizando

Comment: Sim, estava fazendo exatamente isso. Obrigado pela ajuda.